# AutoFs mount failing to reconnect after vpn bounces on macOS Big Sur

Tags: vpn, autofs, macos-bigsur

I have added back the `/net   -hosts   -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid` line that is commented out by default. I then have a symbolic link in my home directory pointing to `/net/<ipAddress>/<mountLocation>/`.

Working scenario:

1. Boot system
2. Connect to VPN
3. cd to mount
4. Everything works

The problem starts when the VPN connection bounces. Even once it's back up. Cd'ing to that directory results in the following.

```
[macbook:~]$ cd workspace
-bash: cd: workspace: Device not configured
```

`sudo automount -cv` doesn't do the trick to reset things. Rebooting seems to be the only thing that does the trick. Previously (Catalina and before), trying to cd to the directory after the VPN connection bounced would simply remount the remote directory.

Answer (score 0):

And the answer was... a simple reboot. System updating from Apple used to be smooth, but this one despite taking maybe a couple of reboots, wasn't quite finished when I logged in again the next day. Eventually I figured out to try a new reboot, and things got fixed.